# At which direction does the two variable function increase most rapidly?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

At which direction does the  function $f(x,y)=ye^{x/y}$ increase most rapidly at point $(1,2)$?

So from what I've seen it should be the same direction as the gradient  at the point.

We have that $f_x=e^{x/y}$ and $f_y=e^{x/y}-\frac{e^{x/y}}{y}$ so $\nabla f(1,2)=(e^{1/2},e^{1/2}-e^{1/2}/2)$. But the solution is in the direction $(2,1)$ so I must've done something incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct, just more complicated.

Remember that *direction* is a ray, so any vector determines a direction, but any other vector that is a positive multiple of that vector determines the same direction. You just need to simplify your expressions and scale a bit. (You should always make easy simplifications anyway.)
$$
\nabla f(1, 2) = \bigl( e^{1/2}, \tfrac12 e^{1/2} \bigr) 
= \tfrac12 e^{1/2} \, (2, 1).
$$

Besides $(2, 1)$ which is nice since its coordinates are integers, as small as possible, there is another "nice answer" to the question *which direction?* That is the **unit** vector:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2}} \, (2, 1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \, (2, 1) 
= \biggl( \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \biggr)
$$

Without more information in the prompt, any of these vectors correctly identify the direction.

Comment: I see thank you for the answer.